# How to make a variable public for all the workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I put this code into the module page

```
    Option Explicit
Dim correct As Boolean

Sub setCorrect()

    correct = True

End Sub

Sub checkCorrectTrue()

    If correct Then

        MsgBox "OK"

    Else

        MsgBox "NO"

    End If

End Sub
```

Then when I call these 2 subs from a sheet my variable *correct* never switch to True

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

    Call setCorrect

    Call checkCorrectTrue

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using `Dim correct As Boolean` it is only available in that module. To be able to use the variable across modules you need to declare it using `Public`

Try using

```
Option Explicit
Public correct As Boolean

Sub setCorrect()

    correct = True

End Sub

Sub checkCorrectTrue()

    If correct Then

        MsgBox "OK"

    Else

        MsgBox "NO"

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What value does it have when you step through it?

Comment: step through your `CommandButton4_Click()` and see if `SetCorrect` gets correctly called. This works fine on my machine - Where are you storing the `CommandButton4_Click()`?

Comment: @Tom Don't you just hate it when that happens.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook The joys of trying to help